# Reject obviously spoofed messages in Exchange 2007 SP2

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-2007, spam, spoofing

I have an Exchange 2007 SP2 server which happily accepts SMTP messages whose sender is **`SomeRandomString@mydomain.com`** and the recipient is **`SomeRealUser@mydomain.com`**; this leads to all sort of spoofing and spam.

Is there any way I can tell Exchange "reject all messages whose sender is in your authoritative SMTP domain but doesn't match any real address you have in the GAL"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

http://exchangepedia.com/blog/2008/09/how-to-prevent-annoying-spam-from-your.html

As usual, being able to set some flag like "block messages sent to recipients not listed in the GAL" would have been a lot easier... what Exchange 2007 certainly doesn't lack in power, it as much certainly does in admin-friendlyness :-/

Comment: i know this is old, but we still have a working ex2007 and strangely enough that is almost literally the caption on the checkbox to enable this in Exchange 2007. it is in Hub Transport > Anti-Spam > Recipient Filtering.
using SPF would also stop those.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, if you are using an edge transport server, otherwise you will need a 3rd party tool. We use a Cisco spam and virus blocker, which was relatively inexpensive, which provides this exact function.

Comment: Are you saying only an ET can filter out those messages? Can't a HT with anti-spam enabled do the same?

Comment: Yes, just not by default. You would need to run the Install-AntisapmAgents.ps1 script. Then enable Recipient filtering and check the box that says Block Messages sent to recipients not listed in the Global Address list.

Comment: That's not what I asked for; I don't want to block messages sent **to** fake **recipients**, I want to block messages sent **from** fake **senders**.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry misunderstood. And that is a great post you found.